# How to set Preview to start on the last viewed page?

Tags: icloud, pdf, preview

There is no problem with `PDF` stored on my mac, it can be started on the last viewed page. However, the problem occurs when I use preview to open PDF files stored on iCloud. It's always shown up the first page. This is really annoying. I must scroll down, hundred of pages.

Has anyone faced this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** When I store a PDF on iCloud using Preview.app It worked fine!!

However, the application that I used is [PDF Reader Pro Edition for iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/pdf-reader-pro-edition-for/id364502063?mt=8). I stored my file using its iCloud option.

When I opened the PDF with Preview.app using [Cloud Mate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud-mate/id623799272) on my Mac.
[image]

I can scroll to page 50 and then  quit the Preview.app. Then reopened the PDF again in the same way I just did.

But the first page is shown instead of the last viewed page which should be page 50.

Comment: on 10.9 I just saved a pdf to a local folder. opened it went to page 101. Closed it and moved it to iCloud. Opened it from there it opened on page 101. Quit Preview opened the pdf again same thing. Scrolled to another page and repeated the open and close no problems..

Comment: @markhunte please see my edited question.

Comment: Are you saying if you store and open the file with PDF Reader Pro.and it does not open back to the last page. And this has nothing to do with Preview.app

Comment: No, I used `Preview` to open it but the file is stored on ICloud of the PDF Reader application.

Comment: Do you mean PDF Reader Pro Edition for iPad and PDFSync for Mac. Also what app is the screenshot from?

Comment: Actually, I am using [PDF Reader Pro Edition](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-reader-pro-edition-for/id364502063?mt=8) on my iPad and [Cloud Mate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud-mate/id623799272) on my Mac. The `Cloud Mate` just facilitate me in order to access files on iCloud. So, I think that it's not a point. The point is all the uploaded files by other application, except Preview. It doesn't remember the last viewed page.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I have reflected this in an edit in your question. I suspect though the issue is with PDF Reader Pro or Cloud Mate. You should contact the venders or see if they have a support fora/forums

Answer (score 1):

There an option in Preview that you need to have enabled:

```
Preferences > PDF > On opening documents (should be checked)
```

[image: Preview PDF Preferences]

*also instead of needing to "scroll down, hundreds of pages" you should be able to simply use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and enter the page number you want to jump to.

Comment: My Preview is set as your figure. It works only for documents stored on Mac, however, it doesn't seem to work for documents on iCloud.

Comment: @LVarayut, interesting, mine stays on the last page viewed (saved on iCloud). Another thing you could try is adding a bookmark `Command-D` and see if it holds. If it doesn't then one of Preview.app's .plist files could be corrupted (`com.apple.Preview`). Essentially how Preview knows what page you were last on is stored in those files as `bookmarks`.

Comment: I just tried adding a bookmark on my Mac and opened the PDF on my IPad. Unfortunately, the application doesn't sync the bookmark!! :( 
Please see my edited question. It may give you more details.

Comment: @LVarayut, I see, my answer was in regards to your original question (before editing it and failing to mention the third party application!). Obviously that application you're using doesn't sync like Preview.app and is an issue you would have to take up with developers.